# Save a jpg image to my webform and link it to my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I have set up a webform for employees to input data, which is connected to a SQL test server with a database I created. I now want to upload an image (.jpg) from the users computer(dir) and save image to the server path (which is currently on my computer for now) into a folder I designated, and save the path to server/database. Also while saving, how can I include the filename with the employee id attached?

Using visual studio 2015, I have already created a fileupload button and onclick button to save everything. When I run the program through the browser (firefox), it seems to run smoothly with no errors. The dignostics tool shows me ASP.NET: Save State completed"/WebF.

After it runs, when I hover my mouse over some text, it shows some parts have worked, up until:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
```

I have checked on this site for different solutions but they don't seem to work. e.g `image.save();` and `image.saveAs();` which haven't worked. Maybe I'm doing it wrong and I don't understand C# yet.

I used an example from Microsofts docs .net help pages but that doesn't seem to work completely.

This is the code I got from Microsofts .net help pages.

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string saveDir = @"~\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EMPMIS\PASSPORTS";

    string MainPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;

    string EMPLOYEEID = TXTEMPID.Text;
    string UserFile = FileUpload1.FileName;

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string savePath = MainPath + EMPLOYEEID + Server.HtmlEncode(UserFile);

        // Append the name of the file to upload to the path.
        //string EMPLOYEEID = TXTEMPID.Text;
        // savePath += fileName + EMPLOYEEID;

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was saved as " + UserFile;
    }
    else
    {
        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
The solution was to change to the saveDir path to an absolute path rather than a relative path, which solved my issue.

string saveDir = @"C:...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EMPMIS\PASSPORTS";

Comment: You need to include code to connect to SQL Server and add the savePath to a database record regarding the file.

Comment: Looks like you path may be incorrect to start, the Request.PhysicalApplicationPath would resolve to your project directory when running the app in Visual Studio, so the saveDir adds more of the same directory to the path? You shouldn't ever store app files in the directory of the site as attackers could guess the urls and take sensitive data, review the following security considerations, around 10% of website vulnerabilities relate to user file inputs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-threat-modeling-tool-input-validation#controls-users

Comment: @betelgeuce I have already done that, which is this?:  string sql = "Insert into Employees(EMPID, NAME, GL) Values (" + int.Parse(TXTEMPID.Text) + ", '" + TXTNAME.Text + "', " + int.Parse(TXTGL.Text) + ")";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @Richard so i should get rid of Request.PhysicalApplicationPath? and use my  save.Dir.

Comment: @1nput_N4me Could you please update your code to reflect this.

Comment: Hi all, it seems to be working now thanks but it wont save into the \PASSPORTS\ folder, only the projects folder. It is giving me this HTTPexception:  ![not rooted](https://photos.app.goo.gl/WaYoBe8rqU9MWqaU9)

Comment: Hi all! I have actually got it working now with no errors. It was an issue with using  relative path instead of the absolute path for the saveDir. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Style="color: black; font-weight: bold; font-size: large;"
                        Text="Image Uploaded." />
                         <asp:FileUpload ID="fupidproof" runat="server" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdidproof" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button ID="btnidproof" runat="server" Text="Upload" Style="background-color: darkcyan;
                                            color: white;" OnClick="btnidproof_Click" />

 --------------------------------aspx.cs code---------------------
  protected void btnidproof_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", con);

            string logopath = "";
            if (fupidproof.HasFile)
            {
                logopath = "~//Kycimg//" + Guid.NewGuid() + fupidproof.FileName;
                hdidproof.Value = logopath.ToString();
                fupidproof.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(logopath));
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", hdidproof.Value, SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblMessage.Text = "Image has been Uploaded Successfully";


    }
```